# why findOne () not return any value in mogooDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

why findOne does not return any value. I am trying to find the user with his email address but this function returning null. and I am exit from the function. help me solve this function, actually, this is a password reset post route. I am getting a username but when I reach to user.findOne () its return me null value . and also token undefined, i don't know how to fix, give me some solution

```
app.post('/check-auth',  (req, res, next)=> {
  console.log(req.body)
    async.waterfall([
      function(done) {
        crypto.randomBytes(20, function(err, buf) {
          var token = buf.toString('hex');
          done(err, token);
        });
      },
      async function(token, done) {
        const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.username });
        console.log(user);

        if (!user) {
          req.flash('error', 'No account with that email address exists.');

          return res.redirect('/forget-password');
        }

// Do your stuff with the user
     
          user.resetPasswordToken = token;
        
          user.resetPasswordExpires = Date.now() + 3600000; // 1 hour
  
          user.save(function(err) {
            done(err, token, user);
          });
       
      },
      function(token, user, done) {
        var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
          service: 'Gmail',
          auth: {
            user: 'xyz@gmail.com',
      pass: 'jvjvsdjfvjdvjdvdv'
          }
        });
        console.log(user.email)
        var mailOptions = {
          
          from: 'passwordreset@demo.com',
          to: req.body.username,
          subject: 'Node.js Password Reset',
          text: 'You are receiving this because you (or someone else) have requested the reset of the password for your account.\n\n' +
            'Please click on the following link, or paste this into your browser to complete the process:\n\n' +
            'http://' + req.headers.host + '/reset/' + token + '\n\n' +
            'If you did not request this, please ignore this email and your password will remain unchanged.\n'
        };
        smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err) {
          req.flash('info', 'An e-mail has been sent to ' + user.email + ' with further instructions.');
          done(err, 'done');
        });
      }
    ], function(err) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      res.redirect('/forgot');
    });
  });
```

Comment: You need to decrypt the token first and get the user's email address from there.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `async, await` with callbacks.

Try that following way.

```
          async function(token, done) {
                 const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.username });
                 console.log(user);
        
                 if (!user) {
                   req.flash('error', 'No account with that email address exists.');
        
                   return res.redirect('/forget-password');
                 }
    
                // Do your stuff with the user
         }
```

If you want to handle errors then wrap the whole code block inside `try and catch`.

I hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: still this return null value sir

Comment: Before query do `console.log(req.body)` and check if you are getting username in the console.

Comment: i am updating my code see tell me sir what is error

Comment: Remove dot after async. `async.waterfall`